# Certain domains (almost) not reachable

Tags: networking, ping

I have a weird problem. My internet connection works fine except for some domains. Two that I found so far:

```
mendeley.com
9gag.com
```

For some reason, their websites do not work in normal Firefox, but they **do** work in Firefox private mode.

Also, ping can resolve the domain names, but gets no response:

```
> ping mendeley.com
PING mendeley.com (54.246.207.205) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- mendeley.com ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 7055ms
```

Other domains work just fine (ping, Firefox, everything smooth). I have tried this from work and home (different net providers), in a VM, and *even on a different Laptop* (also running Ubuntu 14.04). Even in those cases, same result, all (that I have tried) but those two domains work!

It does work normally on Windows and Android, again suggesting that this is not a provider/server side problem. Also, it worked in the past (since some weeks ago, maybe), and I didn't change any network settings since then.

Is that a problem caused by some Canonical update?

Ubuntu 14.04
Firefox 47.0